# Python cannot allocate memory error

Tags: python, multithreading, memory-management, subprocess, popen

I written a python script that spawns about 10 threads and doesn't waits for them. Whereas a thread is spawned, it creates a bash script and it runs it with subprocess.Popen(). Then, the thread stops and exits. So basically, I have 10 threads that terminates in few seconds and then 10 subprocesses that are running. Every process has his code and it's indipendent from the others.Once every process has terminated, a run of the script is completed.
The script repeats each run for at least 15 times.
The problem is that at the third run, the script stops and returns: 
[Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory

The strange thing is that the first two runs do their job perfectly. It seems that after terminating a subprocess or a thread, it doesn't free the memory.

Here a piece of the code:

```
    while(True):
      print "\nEXECUTION "+str(j)+":"

      # CUTTED CODE

      threads = []
      print "Starting parallel execution of subfiles processing..."
      for t in range(numfiles):  # generate t threads
        thread = threading.Thread(target=processing,args=(inputfile,subsize,t+1,j,))
        thread.start()

      # start waiting loop for all the waitfiles

      #WHILE LOOPS that waits here

      print "Executed all "+str(numfiles)+" processes!"  


      j+=1    

      if(j>=maxrun):
        print "Maximum number of runs reached. The computation will stops."
        print "Renaming final output file...",
        print "done."  
        break
    #END MAIN WHILE


def processing(inputfile,subsize,i,j):

  #create file .sh
  shpath = shell+"script_"+str(i)+"_"+str(j)+".sh"
  fp = open(shpath,"w",os.O_NONBLOCK)
  cmd = os.path.abspath(shell)+"/script_"+str(i)+"_"+str(j)+".sh"
  cmd = shell+"./script_"+str(i)+"_"+str(j)+".sh"
  while True:
    try:
      subprocess.Popen([cmd],stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True)
    except OSError as e:
    print (e.strerror+" Cannot execute the process script_"+str(i)+"_"+str(j)+".sh!\nRetrying...")
    continue
    break
  print "Runned script_"+str(i)+"_"+str(j)+".sh"
```

Comment: what is the "size" of your bash script ? (typical memory consumption, run time, ... when not ran from python)

Comment: you should do thread.join() to ensure threads are closing cleanly

Comment: I doubt that there is something wrong in your program (there are too many loops) and starts too many script. To make this clear, just use `ps -ef|grep xxx` to check how many script started by your program.

Comment: But thread.join doesn't only wait for the termination and nothing more?

Comment: Okay, so if your code is perfect elsewhere you can probably get away without using thread.join() but it is certainly good practice and if you're having issues like this it will probably help you track them down. For example, are you sure that the waiting loop is doing its job correctly? You should retain a handle to all the threads you started (keeping them in a list) so that you can check. Same goes for subprocess.